# azure table storage from outside

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

When using azure table storage from an app outside cloud does the speed of a transaction decrease and by how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, due to network latency. How much depends on how far away the machine making the call is from the Azure data center.

Comment: Any other reasons besides latency? I mean there is network latency inside the cloud just as well, isn't it? App machine and data server not necessarily in the same data center.

Comment: There is latency within the cloud yes, but this will increase significantly when services are geographically separated as data is flowing over the open web rather than the internal Azure network. Also you'll incur additional bandwidth charges when your app server is outside the data center, that said, these charges may be trivial if you're not transmitting much data.

Comment: I'm currently using table storage to log SQL exceptions. My App Server is located in the UK and the table storage service is in the Ireland datacenter, costs and latency for me are almost negligible. But it's not a critical part of the app.